# pandas DataFrame.to_sql only seeming to send headers to the MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a program to take data in from a weather station via an arduino, format it in columns, and save it to a MySQL table (later will make a simple website where the most recent data is called up and presented).

My python code is:

```
import serial
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from io import StringIO
from dbfwrite import dftodbf
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "COM5", baudrate=115200, timeout=3)

tableName="mainframe"
weatherstring = ""
startnumber=0
dfmain=pd.DataFrame()

while (startnumber<1):
    if(serialPort.in_waiting > 0):
        currentLine = serialPort.readline()
        weatherstring = currentLine.decode('utf-8')
        check = weatherstring[0:2] == "c:"
        if check == True:
            wsio = StringIO(weatherstring)
            df1=pd.read_csv(wsio, sep=",", header=None, names = ['PacketsLostPackets','PercentOfPackets','SignalStregnth','ErrorCheck','Rain','RainRate','Humidity','Solar','Temp','UV','vcap','vsolar','WindD','WindDRaw','WindGust','WindGustD','WindV'])
            print(df1)
            dfmain=dfmain.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
            dftodbf.dbfwrite(dfmain, "C:\\Users\\jjdef\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\weather\\output\\output.dbf")
            engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:lolguy123@127.0.0.1:3306')
            with engine.connect() as connection:
                try:
                    dfmain.to_sql(tableName, connection, schema='weather', if_exists='replace');
                except ValueError as vx:
                    print(vx)
                except Exception as ex:   
                    print(ex)
                else:
                    print("Table %s created successfully."%tableName);   
                    print(dfmain)
                finally:
                    connection.close()
```

the `dfmain` dataframe prints correctly every cycle with the correct number of rows, but when I go check MySQL workbench, when i click the "select 1000 rows" function to display the table, it only seems to have the headers saved (image below).
I have checked the pandas, pymysql, and sqlalchemy docs and everything seems to check out. I'm a relative beginner, so I definitley have done something wrong and am likely the one to blame, but im not sure what.

Anyone have any idea why this is behaving this way and/or how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance!
JJ

Screenshot of mysql with only one row (the header row):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: try to print dfmain and check weather the dataframe is printing are not in the output

Comment: @appu
in my code, I have it print dfmain during every cycle, and the dataframe "dfmain" is correct in the print. im almost certain it is an issue with the way the setup for the pandas to mysql stuff is